# how to pass a value to second argument where first argument is as default argument in function

Tags: php

Actually i want to pass a value to the second argument in a function , where the first argument is as default argument.

```
<?php
function a($a=5,$b) {
echo "a = ".$a."<br>";
echo "b = ".$b;
} 
a(,3);


?>
```

the first argument should remain default.

Comment: It never ever should be written like this.

Comment: Pass the default or swap the function's parameters around. Your choice.

Comment: I don't even understand the question oO

Comment: i dont want to pass again because thats default and also i dont want swap how can pass value for second argument only like this. #oGeez

Comment: `i dont want swap` _tough_, to be honest. If you think its a case of `i need to not swap`, then you have a bigger underlying problem. What's your _need_ to try and do it this way? Or is it just at your preference?

Comment: i want just try with this concept only pass value for second argument. @MLeFevre

Comment: One solution to this would be to wait for PHP 5.6, which might contain precisely this feature... Probably not much of a short term solution, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this case is to revert parameters:

```
function a($b,$a=5) {}
```

and just call

```
a(3);
```

Comment: better yet if $a is always to be the default just remove it from the parameters :)

Comment: dear hsz this is the other type function my query actually focus on other concept if we pass first argument default and want to pass value of the function at running time how is it possible?

Comment: You can use constants for example: `define('DEFAULT_A', 5); function a($a = DEFAULT_A, $b){ ... }; a(DEFAULT_A, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

you can't !

It's horrible.
Write your function in the other side :

```
function a($b, $a = 5) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code : change the function parameter position.

```
<?php
function a($b,$a=5) {
   echo "a = ".$a."<br>";
   echo "b = ".$b;
} 
a(3);

?>
```